# Got 'None's when doing a bisection search determining whether a single character is in an alphabetical-ordered string or not

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, recursion, bisection

As mentioned in the title, I got 'None's when I run this piece of code.

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    '''
    char: a single character
    aStr: an alphabetized string

    returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
    '''
    if len(aStr)==0:
        return False
    elif len(aStr)==1:
        return aStr==char
    elif aStr[(len(aStr)/2)]==char:
        return True
    elif aStr[(len(aStr)/2)]>char:
        return isIn(char, aStr[:(len(aStr)/2)])
    elif aStr[(len(aStr)/2)]<aStr:
        return isIn(char, aStr[(len(aStr)/2):])

isIn('n', 'abfnuv')
```

I have checked it for a few times, and I think it might happen in the process when judging aStr is equal to char or not, but I don't know how to correct it, or how it happens.
Thanks in advance for anyone reading this thread!

For more information:

I use canopy python-2.7, and when I used 'run the current file' button, it returned None, but when I used 'run the selected text' button, it returned True.
How could this happen?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't mention I use python-2.7, so I think I will not get a TypeError when doing (len(aStr)/2).

Comment: For your test case I get `True`. If `char` is not found, you'll get `None` as eventually you fall off the `if..elif..elif` branches and don't return anything.

Comment: Ah, no, you are correct, floor division applies, and I did see the 2.7 tag. Time for the caffeine hit.

Comment: So to put it another way: I do **not** get `None` when I run your code. I get `True` (from the print statement), `True` (the returned value echoed by my interactive session).

Comment: I just forgot to add the 2.7 tag, and I added it just now...maybe before you read this thread. And what confused me is when I ran this in my computer, it didn't show True. How could this happen?

Comment: I don't know; are you 100% sure you are running *this very code*?

Comment: And I felt really sorry about not mentioning my environment is canopy python-2.7. Is there something relevant to the software I'm using?

Comment: Holy shi... I forgot to remove the test sentence printing 'True' in that branch...I'll remove it right now. So sorry.

Comment: You also have indented the `inStr()` call (last line) to be part of the function. It'll never run that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two bugs in your tests.

You are testing against the whole list, containing one element, here:

```
elif len(aStr)==1:
    return aStr==char
```

`aStr` may be set to `['n']` and it'll still not be equal to `'n'`. Use indexing:

```
elif len(aStr)==1:
    return aStr[0]==char
```

Next, you are testing against the list again here:

```
elif aStr[(len(aStr)/2)]<aStr:
```

That branch tests against the `aStr` list, not against `char`. Python 2 allows this kind of comparison, but will sort the types by type name in this case. `str` is always going to be greater than `list`, so that branch is *always* true.

Test against `char` instead:

```
elif aStr[(len(aStr)/2)]<char:
```

Still, even with these errors corrected, you actually still manage to return `True` for the given sample:

```
>>> isIn('n', 'abfnuv')
True
```

because the `n` character happens to be located exactly at the first midpoint you test.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this should exactly be the problem I had in the code. I'll rewrite it to ensure I have understood what you've suggested. Thanks for your patience! :) Wish you a good day!